# Trying to Create a TAR Archive, But Exclude .messages Files

Tags: tar, gzip

I want to create a GZIP compressed TAR archive containing the contents of /var/log, but excluding /var/log/messages file.

I tried `tar -cvf var/log.tar var/log/ -x *.messages*`, but got the error message:

```
tar: You may not specify more  than one `-Acdtrux' or `--test-label' option
```

Any ideas on how to go about this? I'm pretty confident I can create the archive, just not sure how to exclude the /var/log/messages file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-x` flag (short for `--extract`) tells `tar` to unpack an archive. The `-c` flag (short for `--create`) tells `tar` to create an archive. You're passing both flags, which is a contradiction. It looks like you probably want to use the `--exclude` flag instead of the `-x` flag, e.g.:

```bsh
tar -cvf var/log.tar var/log --exclude='*.messages*'
```

Comment: Thanks! That was a  huge help. I ended up doing `tar -cvf log.tar /var/log --exclude=/var/log/messages` and it worked like a charm.